# Proof By Counterexample, pigeonhole

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is from a discrete math homework question. I really don't know where to begin, except that I understand the concept of a proof by counterexample, just not how to get to it.

In the statement of the pigeonhole, we argued that $$\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}m\right\rfloor+1=\left\lceil\frac{n}m\right\rceil\;.$$

Prove that this is generally not true.

Comment: A good way to start is by throwing numbers at it and seeing what happens.

Comment: Wrote the LaTeX for you. But now that I'm looking at it I'm not sure that this is what you meant. Why would you take the floor or ceiling of an integer? Maybe you meant fraction, and not "choose"?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein $M$ and $m$ are different, is that expected? Could be $n \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't modify that from the original text. Also using "choose" with non-integers is not really done, I think, in beginning discrete math courses (but, maybe? @Marla - can you clarify?).

Comment: @Yoni: Taking the pigeonhole context into account, I’ll bet that Marla meant $$\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}m\right\rfloor+1=\left\lceil\frac{n}m\right\rceil\;,$$ and not binomial coefficients at all.

Comment: It is supposed to be floor of n-1/ m    + 1  is equal to ceiling of n/m

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: That sounds plausible. The original question explicitly said "choose", so I guess it might be a case of mis-copying the question.

Comment: You two are right, choose was just a mistake on my end.

Comment: Fixed now. ${}{}$

Answer (score 7):

HINT: The identity

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}m\right\rfloor+1=\left\lceil\frac{n}m\right\rceil$$

is valid for positive integers $m$ and $n$, so you’ll have to look elsewhere for a counterexample. What if $m=-1$ and $n$ is some positive integer? what if $m=1$ and $n$ is not an integer at all?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll play around with that.

Comment: @Marla: You’re welcome; let me know if you get totally stuck.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see we are on the same wavelength. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

If it is not assumed that $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then consider $m=3$ and $n=3.5$